# How do I disable a Chromium flag?

Tags: snap, chromium

I am on Ubuntu desktop 20.04 months ago, while hunting a rogue browser extension, I set the `--disable-site-isolation-trials` flag for my chromium-browser install.

**Problem:** many moons later, I cannot figure out how to remove the flag.

##### Troubleshooting

- Inside chromium I reset all flags and relaunched chromium, but that had no effect
- I checked `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` there isn't a flag setting
  `~/.local/share/applications` doesn't have a chromium launcher
- I check my `bashrc` and I couldn't find a flags (via alias or exported)
- I tried `export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="--enable-site-isolation-trials"` but it is just ignored and the browser continues warning me about `--disable-site-isolation-trials`

**Even more weird -ish:**
I ran `locate chromium.desktop` to find the actual launcher for my chromium

```
/snap/chromium/2254/bin/chromium.desktop
/snap/chromium/2254/meta/gui/chromium.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop
```

and confirmed that there are zero flags set via the launcher(s).

```
root@machine:/snap/bin# grep "Exec=" /snap/chromium/2254/bin/chromium.desktop
Exec=chromium %U
Exec=chromium
Exec=chromium --incognito
Exec=chromium --temp-profile
root@machine:/snap/bin# grep "Exec=" /snap/chromium/2254/meta/gui/chromium.desktop
Exec=chromium %U
Exec=chromium
Exec=chromium --incognito
Exec=chromium --temp-profile
root@machine:/snap/bin# grep "Exec=" /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop /snap/bin/chromium %U
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop /snap/bin/chromium
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop /snap/bin/chromium --incognito
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/chromium_chromium.desktop /snap/bin/chromium --temp-profile
```

from there I used the command line to reset all pf chromium's flags:

```
snap set chromium command.chromium=""
```

It seems to excute successfully, the actual net result.. is nothing.

And when I check `htop`  it appears `/snap/chromium/2254/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome` is being run with several flags `--disable-site-isolation-trials --render-process-limit=10 --disable-feature=TFLiteLanguageDetectEnabled`

stumped... where are these flags being read from?

**Update:**

```
$ sudo snap get chromium command.chromium
chromium
```

Also I need to correct my comment below... I just noticed that an `htop` filter **STILL** shows...
`/snap/chromium/2254/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --disable-site-isolation-trials --render-process-limit=10 --disable-feature=TFLiteLanguageDetectEnabled`... my apologies, guess I was looking at the wrong line of output..

Comment: What's the output of `declare -p CHROMIUM_FLAGS`?

Comment: I finally figured it out... when I switch my chromium from the ppa version to the snap version, chromium-common, chromium-sandbox, and another file was leftover and causing the problem...    chromium snap didn't have any flags as I described... but after I finally ran "sudo apt autoremove"... the problem immediately vanished.... fyi `declare -p CHROMIUM_FLAGS` doesn't work, just get `bash: declare: CHROMIUM_FLAGS: not found`

Comment: Spoke too soon.. I still get the warning about the flags when I start chromium...  however when I check `htop` the warnings no longer appear... I am thoroughly confused again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of additional places where you might set Chromium flags. In order of probability:

- The internal page `about://flags` (a URL to type in Chromium's address bar).
- The file [`$HOME/.chromium-browser.init`](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Echromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source/tree/launcher/chromium.launcher?h=stable#n89).

Note that the `--disable-feature=TFLiteLanguageDetectionEnabled` is set by [`chromium.launcher` itself](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Echromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source/tree/launcher/chromium.launcher?h=stable#n121), so the only user defined flags you need to track down are `--disable-site-isolation-trials` and `--render-process-limit=10`.

> I tried `export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="--enable-site-isolation-trials"` but it is just ignored

You made a mistake, you meant `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`, not `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS`.

Sidenote: You can always check out the exact command line used to invoke Chromium in `about://version`.

Comment: you just made my evening.. I made a hot pot of tea ready to spend the evening purging chromium from my system...  the culprit `$HOME/.chromium-browser.init`  It just seems like an oversight that developers give so many ways to add flags neglect to provide a simple way to determine "where" whatever flag is coming from...the `about://version` seems like a great location to add that info.. to avoid this problem... a very maddening week... THANKS A LOT  (ps, you beat chatgpt :-P )

Comment: @nightwatch Great to hear that! Yeah, too many ways to set flags, but `.chromium-browser.init` is a legacy one (IIRC a relic from Debian). I considered dropping it (see discussion at [LP: #1514484](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1514484)), but then probably many users would be upset...